# Definition not found for print()

Tags: c++, string, class

New to C++ and trying to better understand why my code is giving me some red squiggly.

My code is

```
string print() {
string answer = "";
for(int i = 0; i < numOfElements - 1; i++) {
    answer += (arr[i] + '0');
    answer += ',';
```

I am getting the error under print and also my first bracket {

Not sure if I need to post more, but I don't really get the problem I am having.

```
expected a ';' 
Function definition for 'print' not found.
```

Error when I highlight the code.

Even when I do put a semi colon I get the same error.

Thanks for the help, and appreciate it.

```
class DynamicArray {
private:
    int *arr;
    int arraySize;
    int numOfElements;

DynamicArray(int arraySize) {
    if (arraySize <= 1)
        arr = new int[1];
    else
        arr = new int[arraySize];
}

DynamicArray(const DynamicArray &a) {
    arr = new int[a.arraySize];
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.numOfElements; i++) {
        arr[i] = a.arr[i];
    }
    numOfElements = a.numOfElements;
    arraySize = a.arraySize;
}
public:
    int getArraySize() {
        return arraySize;
    }
    int getNumOfElements() {
        return numOfElements;
    }

};
string print() {
    string answer = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfElements - 1; i++) {
        answer += (arr[i] + '0');
        answer += ',';
    }
    answer += (arr[numOfElements - 1] + '0');
    return answer;
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a complete example? This is missing a lot of code and isn't valid. Normally you should stick with the `std::` prefix, don't include `using namespace std` as that has the potential to cause conflict.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Probably an error above that that's giving the compiler fits. Missing `;` before a closebrace in previous function? [mcve] required. Mind you you'll probably get half done making the MCVE and find the error yourself. That's what makes the MCVE really cool.

Comment: Hi @tadman I unfortunately don't have much control over this, since this is for my programming class at school.

Comment: You have to define the `print` function. What code comes before the line with the error?

Comment: @tadman I think it's unreasonable to expect programmers to type "std::" before every library call. It's even worse coding style to name variables the same as a variable in the standard library (Never name something cout, cin, endl, vector, map, etc.), so `using namespace std` actually acts like a linter xD. The error "ambiguous reference to XYZ" is very obvious and self explanatory, and it's easy to just do `::cout` if you really want to name your own variable `cout` and overcome the ambiguous reference.

Comment: I updated my to show my above code and it was something to do with brackets, now I just get squiggly under my "numOfElements" , "arr" and "arraySize"

Comment: What IS important is to _never_ write a top-level `using namespace XYZ;` in a header file. Then you force `using namespace XYZ;` upon those who include you, _and_ it's not clear that this happens. If you want it in a header file, wrap it in brackets so you dont pollute the namespace of those who include your file.

Comment: @Ripi2 Only classes/structs should have to do this, not functions. The error here is something weirder and I think out of scope from the code he posted.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, but... warning: In `DynamicArray(int arraySize)`, the `arraySize` function parameter shadows the `arraySize` member leading to much fun and debugging later.

Comment: @PKPython Please work on your code to get an MCVE. Get one contiguous cpp file (and headers if that's part of the issue) that causes the issue, and keep removing code until the error goes away. Keep all code that is necessary to cause the error, and make sure the code you post is ready to throw into a compiler. This code you posted will not compile.

Comment: Sorry guys for wasting your time, it's really confusing to explain how it needs to be done. We have a 'main.cpp' file that is going to include this file into it, so that it can compile. Maybe that's why it's confusing

Comment: Is `print` intended to be a  `DynamicArray` class member? Currently it is not, but it sure looks like it's trying to use the `DynamicArray` member variables.

Comment: `numOfElements` is never initialized. This will lead to future chaos.

Comment: I thought I did in the class DyanmicArray? I put int numOfElements;

Comment: Good on you for implementing copy constructor, but to finish off [The Rule Of Three](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) you'll need an assignment operator, a destructor, and make the copy constructor `public`. Also reconsider `private` constructors unless you're also going to have a `static` factory function.

Comment: You have `int numOfElements;` but you use it before assigning a value to it. For example, what is the value of `numElements` when the program reaches `for (int i = 0; i <= a.numOfElements; i++) `? There is no way to know. The `for` loop could loop a billion times. It could loop zero. Also note that C++ arrays are origin zero, and that means `int i = 0; i <= a.numOfElements` allows a rwange of [0,`numElements`], not [0,`numElements`). You'll be off by one.

Comment: Suggestion. Once you get the program compiling, don't add any more code until you have tested and proven all of the code you currently have. If you build more code on a faulty foundation you'll likely have to fix even more bugs and possibly throw it out.